# two dygraph in RStudio Viewer pane

Tags: r, rstudio, dygraphs

Is it possible to simultaneously view two `dygraph`s in RStudio Viewer pane?

I am updating an old function that produces two time-series plots (using ggplot2), stacked one above the other (using `gridExtra::grid.arrange(ggp1, ggp2)`). I want to use the cool `dygraph` and the change is pretty straightforward, ..., except that I would like to view both plots simultaneously in RStudio Viewer pane.

It is possible to view one plot at a time. Indeed, ["If you call `dygraph` within RStudio then it’s output appears within the Viewer pane"](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/r-console.html). But I couldn't find a trick to display both plots at the same time. And I want that, because I want to use the handy [synchronization](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/gallery-synchronization.html) feature of `dygraph`

For the sake of a reproducible example, here's an example of what I am doing.

```
library(dygraphs)   
dygraph(mdeaths, group = "ensync")
dygraph(fdeaths, group = "ensync")
```

But every one of these is a new call in R Console and then the first plot is displayed on the viewer and immediately the second plot replaces it.

The only workaround I found is put it in an RMarkdown document and knitr it all. But I kind of dislike this approach. It would be more convenient for me directly displaying it in RStudio Viewer pane.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe using shiny with one different tabpanel for each dygraph

Comment: thanks, yeah, `shiny` is an option. I am currently using `rmarkdown` to address my issue, though. I put the code for the `dygraphs` in an .Rmd file and then from my code call `rmarkdown::render()` and then send the output file to `rstudioapi::viewer()`. Note: the output_file have to be "within the R session temporary directory" ?rstudioapi::viewer

Comment: if you are using rmarkdown, take a look at http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/index.html

Comment: thanks. I'll have a look. Although I was not actually using rmarkdown in this particular case. I ended up using it only as a workaround to display two dygraphs in RStudio Viewer pane

Answer (score 16):

Using `htmltools` package, insert the two `dygraph`s in a `tagList` and use the `browsable()` function to plot both graphs in the viewer:

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmltools)

browsable(
  tagList(
    dygraph(mdeaths, group = "ensync", height = 200, width = "100%"),
    dygraph(fdeaths, group = "ensync", height = 200, width = "100%")
    )
  )
```

Maybe the code is more readable with the `magrittr` forward-pipe operator :

```
library(dygraphs)
library(htmltools)
library(magrittr)

dygraph(mdeaths, group = "ensync", height = 200, width = "100%") %>%
  tagList(dygraph(fdeaths, group = "ensync", height = 200, width = "100%")) %>%
  browsable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with dygraphs, but here's an alternate solution using zoo and plotly packages

(i) Use zoo to transform ts class objects into a combined data.frame

```
library(zoo)
m.dat <- data.frame(date=as.Date(as.yearmon(time(mdeaths))), Deaths=as.matrix(mdeaths), Sex="M")
f.dat <- data.frame(date=as.Date(as.yearmon(time(fdeaths))), Deaths=as.matrix(fdeaths), Sex="F")
dat <- rbind(m.dat, f.dat)
```

(ii) Plot a combined data.frame with ggplot2

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=date, y=Deaths, group=Sex, colour=Sex)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

(iii) Use plotly::ggplotly to transform the graph into an interactive graph

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(p)
```

Here's a screenshot of compare view of a data point.

[image]

Comment: thanks, ..., I did not use `plotly` to convert my `ggplot2` because I actually need two plots and not the two lines in one plot (different scales, that `ggplot2` does not allow to show on the same plot -e.g. secondary axis-). So I am combining the two plots with `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`, but `plotly` does not handle well this kind of thing. Nor, in my experience, handle ggplot facets nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that romles' approach works for me in RStudio, although it seems to render the plots at such a size that they need both vertical and horizontal scrollbars to fully view. So there is presumably a sizing option somewhere that needs to be invoked on most monitors.

Comment: You can change the `dygraph` plot dimensions using the *width* and *height* arguments.